# Selecionar o encoding UTF-8 Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: codificação-de-caracteres, aptana

Não estou encontrando o lugar para configurar o encoding no Aptana, se alguém puder ajudar ?

Comment: Ele é baseado no eclipse então tente, menu `window>preference` no treeview `general>workspace` text encoding vai definir o encode de todos os arquivos criados.

Comment: achei aqui é no workspace,,, vlw,,, E no mysql qual aqruivo configuro?

Comment: Não entendi a parte do MySQL, é definir o encode da base?

Comment: Tava lendo aqui que tem um lugar pra configurar->default-character-set=utf8<- mai num tô achando isso no my.ini, se sabe qual arquivo configura isso?

Comment: Isso já é outra pergunta :P, se não existe essa configuação no sey my.ini adicione ela, reinicie o MySQL. Pode ver se o valor alterado rodando essa consulta `show variables`

Comment: Oh ->> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139450/como-configurar-charset-utf-8-no-mysql se puder me ajudar como configuro isso no my.ini...