# Como configurar charset=utf-8 no Mysql?

Tags: mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou tentado configurar o `charset=utf-8` no MYSQL, mas não encontro no arquivo my.ini. Em qual arquivo configuro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui adicionado no próprio my.ini

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Creditos para @Guilherme Nascimento.. ;) vlw